# JQuery AJAX Consume SOAP Web Service

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

I have been experimenting and trying to learn JQuery, using AJAX to consume a SOAP web service I had written some time ago.  Below is the code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var webServiceURL = 'http://local_server_name/baanws/dataservice.asmx?op=GetAllCategoryFamilies';
    var soapMessage = '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><GetAllCategoryFamilies xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" /></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope';

    function CallService()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: webServiceURL, 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml", 
            data: soapMessage, 
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: OnSuccess, 
            error: OnError
        });

        return false;
    }

    function OnSuccess(data, status)
    {
        alert(data.d);
    }

    function OnError(request, status, error)
    {
        alert('error');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
    });
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Call Web Service" onclick="CallService(); return false;" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently, the method being called in the web service returns an array of category families that contain a category code and a category description.  Since the method returns XML, I set the ajax query accordingly.  However, when I run the app,  I get an 'error' alert box - I am sure what would be causing the problem.  I know the web service works, it's called several hundred times a day by other .NET web apps that I've written.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: As a side note, your soapMessage variable is missing the final `">"` at the end of the soap envelope.

Comment: @Kyle Crap, that was it!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try setting `processData: false` flag. This flag is `true` by default and I guess jQuery is [converting](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) your XML to string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: webServiceURL, 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml", 
    data: soapMessage, 
    processData: false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: OnSuccess, 
    error: OnError
});
```

Comment: This and the missing ">" at the end of my soap message fixed it.  Thanks!