# How do I replicate social ajax calls made internally by SharePoint 2010?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I see that SharePoint 2010 makes javascript ajax calls to some pretty slick internal services like

```
https://<server>/_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json

https://<server>/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json
```

how are these different than something like `https://<server>/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx` which has documentation. There are some requests used by those internal calls which I would really like to be able to duplicate. Any help would be appreciated.

Watching the console which pressing the "Tags & Notes" button you can see SharePoint make a single ajax post to `https://<server>/_vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/GetSocialTagInternal` which it sends a very concise `data : '{"targetPage":"your url here","maximumItemsToReturn":"12"}'` and receives in kind a very pretty:

```
{
   "d":{
      "MyTags":[
         {
            "Term":"I like it",
            "TermFullPathName":"[Keywords:I like it]",
            "TermID":"9f2d5361-a23f-4d95-be9b-f9d385a0f5b9",
            "Path":"I like it",
            "IsPrivate":false
         }
      ],
      "OtherTags":[
         {
            "Term":"I like it",
            "TermFullPathName":"[Keywords:I like it]",
            "TermID":"9f2d5361-a23f-4d95-be9b-f9d385a0f5b9",
            "Path":"I like it",
            "IsPrivate":false
         },
...
```

If anyone can think of any way to get that kind of a return from an existing SP web service I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: It is highly likely that those services have `internal` in their name for the same reason you can't find documentation: Microsoft doesn't want you to use them.  If you use them, there's no guarantee that Microsoft will not break the API (and your program) in future releases.

Comment: It's likely there is documentation *internally* at Microsoft, but since it's *internal* you can't access it. :) If you have a *private* office in your building, do you publish where you hide the key to it? Of course not - it's *private*. *Internal* means "not available to the public for use".

Comment: That would be fine, if they had chosen to expose reasonable alternatives. Instead they use json POSTs internally to do useful things (like retrieve a user's tags on a url) and expose GARBAGE for me to use by making soap calls to get a list of every url a user tagged with a given tag.

Comment: Sharepoint question's don't fare very well on SO. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint2010

Comment: @Diodeus Oh I know, hence the bounty for such a stupid question which should be easily answerable with proper documentation. Why would developers for such a secretive backwards system be participating in SO?

Comment: Why is sharepoint such a pain? Everyone I know who works with it, hates it.

Comment: The deeper "why" is a complex issue involving Microsoft's business model. The simple reasons are that it is an overly complicated, standards avoiding, black-box of bad ideas.

Comment: Is your question how to get a JSON-formatted response from the public SharePoint services? Or how to use the internal services yourself?

Comment: The question is how to do what they do. They manage to get YOUR TAGS on a url. If you can think of ANY way to do that I would be grateful. The fact that they get to use JSON for their internal services while I have to make SOAP calls is just insult to injury.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.gettags.aspx) is the exact web service call you are looking for. Tt is SOAP and not JSON but other than that it does what you ask and returns the Tags of the current user on the specified URL, namely an array of [`SocialTagDetail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialtagdetail_members.aspx) with all details...

To call a SOAP web service via javascript see these:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx
- [JQuery AJAX Consume SOAP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client
- http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/
- http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/

Comment: /facepalm Thank you Yahia, I could have sworn that I had looked at all of the web services. Apparently I fail at reading, GetTags does indeed GetTagsOfUserOnUrl, just with a shorter name ;)