# Talking to SOAP API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soap, cross-domain

I'm trying to fetch data from a SOAP API using Javascript and a simple PHP proxy. When I go to the testing site and manually plug in the parameters I get the correct response. However, when I use the following script, I just get the html of the default testing page, no actual data from the API.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data: {requrl: 'http://rc.api.sitexdata.com/sitexapi/sitexapi.asmx?op=AddressSearch&' + $.param(requestData) },
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

proxy.php

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents($_GET['requrl']);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: PHP has SOAP library. You probably want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see anything in your code that has anything to do with SOAP.  You pass a URL to a php endpoint that fetches the file contents of a remote file.  That's not SOAP.

Technicality aside, does accessing proxy.php through a browser produce different results than what the ajax call produces?  If not, I would double check your documentation on the SOAP call to ensure you're making the call correctly.  If the problem is only occurring when you use ajax, you are probably just missing the dataType and contentType settings.

This link may be useful.  [JQuery AJAX Consume SOAP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service)