# AJAX call to a SOAP remote web service?

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap, web, service

I am trying to connect to a SOAP Web service using AJAX call.

This is my code:

```
<script>
        var webServiceURL = "http://some.ip.address/NameOfService.svc";
        var soapMessage =
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                '<soap:Body>'+
                '<GetName>'+
                '<UserId>' +319+ '</UserId>'+
                '</GetName>'+
                '</soap:Body>'+
                '</soap:Envelope>';

        $("#btn").click(function(){
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: webServiceURL,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset='utf-8'",
                headers: {
                    SOAPAction: "http://some.ip.address/NameOfService.svc/GetName"
                },
                data: soapMessage,
                success: function(soapResponse){
                    $('#test').html(soapResponse);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving 404 error on the browser console. Please, help?

UPDATE:

I tried different approach, using this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/

My code is this:

```
<script>
        $.soap({
            url: 'http://some.ip/NameOfService.svc?wsdl',
            method: 'GetName',
            data: {
                userId: 389
            },

            success: function (soapResponse) {
                // do stuff with soapResponse
                // if you want to have the response as JSON use soapResponse.toJSON();
                // or soapResponse.toString() to get XML string
                // or soapResponse.toXML() to get XML DOM
                console.log(soapResponse)
            },
            error: function (soapResponse) {
                // show error
                console.log(soapResponse)
            }
        });
    </script>
```

And again I receive error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load service.  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service

processData: false

Comment: I added processData: false, but it doesn't work. Maybe I am doing something else wrong too?

Comment: What do you see in the console network tab?  That should give you all the details of the ajax request and response.

Comment: I updated my question. I really need help for this.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with your original code. However, I notice that you have enabled CORS, so I assume this is a cross-domain request. The server must be configured to allow these requests or your ajax will fail. See: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: Yes, this is a cross-domain request. Actually this is a Phonegap mobile application and I test it on my browser (with local server).