# How to call soap api using GET method in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, soap

I have develop a project in angular 2. I need to call soap api using GET method in angular 2. I already use soap in angularjs 1 and soap packages are really easy to use. For angular 2 there is no packages. Is there any packages available in npm for accessing soap api?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a nodejs running, try this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-soap

Answer (score 0):

One way to use the SOAP API would be to include jquery in your application and can use it purely for Ajax calls. Trigger the services you need using jquery and pass the data to angular once response is returned.

Also, to get the data in Json, you can specify the same in your Ajax method and jquery would convert it for you.

You can also refer the [link here for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service).