# AJAX: parameters is always null XML format

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio

I have created a `[WebMethod]` in my server side as shown below:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string ReadComments(string pagenum)
{
    return pagenum;
}
```

and the ajax code:

```
 function GetCommentItems() {
    var pageTrack = $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_layouts/15/Load5MoreComments/CommentFetchSvc.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/ReadComments'); },
        data: '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ReadComments xmlns="http://tempuri.org"><pagenum>testStr</pagenum></ReadComments></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>',
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            var newPageTrack = $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val();
            $("input[id$='pageTrack']").val(parseInt(newPageTrack) + 1);
        },
        error: function (xhr, msg) {
            console.log(msg + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });        
}
```

I am passing a `testStr` as a parameter but it goes always null.
I tried this `processData: false,` but did not work
Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery AJAX Consume SOAP Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service)

Comment: `but it goes always null` - what does? the `pagenum` in c# or `msg` in the success callback in javascript? (or are you hitting the error callback?)

Comment: the `pagenum` in c# is always null

Comment: change data as this data: { "pagenum": testStr}

Comment: @Praveen - so, send json? instead of XML?

Comment: Yes send it as application/json

Comment: so, a SOAP backend can accept JSON just like that? (remarkable)

Comment: OP - try the `processData: false` as in the duplicate marked by @PankajMakwana

Comment: @Praveen I tried with `data: { "pagenum": testStr}` but I am getting 400 error `400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @JaromandaX it goes again null I tried it before

Comment: @JaromandaX If I send JSON I get an `500 error`

Comment: I meant this data: "{ pagenum:" + testStr + "}"

Comment: @Iamnderon - good thing **I** never suggested you change your whole paradigm from XML to JSON, that was someone else ... did you try `processData: false`

Comment: `I meant this data` - oh, @Praveen, so a string which looks a bit like JSON, but is in fact not valid JSON? and will fail, because there is no var called `testStr`

Comment: @Praveen still getting `400 (Bad Request)` I think you are sending the parameter like JSON format

Comment: @JaromandaX I just tried `processData: false` but with no luck. it goes null

Comment: hmm, interesting that your `WebMethod` declares a `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml` ... how (and where) is the Request Format specified?

Comment: I can change the format to response JSON but I always get an 500 error, so with XML format problem is only in parameter

Comment: I was asking about how the request format is specified

Comment: Due to the noob level I am feeling I don't get what you are asking