# How to consume wsdl SOAP web service from PHP or ajax

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service from PHP or AJAX, it's suposed that my ws provider allowed my VPS IP, so the web service works from [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html), but I need to use the data on my web page (running in my VPS), so I've tryed by using this PHP:

```
<?php
$wsdl = "https://an.url?wsdl";
$options = array(
     'Usuario' => "anUser",
     'Clave' => "aPassword",
     'Rut' => "someData",
     'Dv' => "someMoreData"
);
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($client,true).'</pre>';
?>
```

But it throws this error:

[image]

The thing is that I'm tring to acces to the method called "obtenerReporteFinal" and I don't know where to specify that and maybe that's the first mistake.

So I've searched for another method to consume a SOAP web service and I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service) post using ajax. Since I have a PHP+JavaScript web page on my VPS, I've tryed with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" id="btnQlo" value="Call Web Service" />


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $(document).on("click","#btnQlo",function(){CallService()});
});


function CallService()
{
    var webServiceURL = 'https://an.url?wsdl';
    var soapMessage = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://another.url/">';
    soapMessage+='<soapenv:Header/>';
        soapMessage+='<soapenv:Body>'
            soapMessage+='<com:obtenerReporteFinal>'
                soapMessage+='<!--Optional:-->'
                    soapMessage+='<arg0>'
                    soapMessage+='<Usuario>anUser</Usuario>'
                    soapMessage+='<Clave>aPassword</Clave>'
                    soapMessage+='<Rut>someData</Rut>'
                    soapMessage+='<Dv>someMoreData</Dv>'
                soapMessage+='</arg0>'
            soapMessage+='</com:obtenerReporteFinal>'
        soapMessage+='</soapenv:Body>'
    soapMessage+='</soapenv:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: "xml", 
        data: soapMessage,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if I'm now calling the "obtenerReporteFinal" method right, but when I press the button to call the service, it just throws this error: [![enter image description here][4]][4]

If 'http://localhost' is blocked, how could my web service provider allows it for me?

So, how can I make this work on any of the above cases? I'm really confused since this is the first time I have to consume a SOAP Web Service.

**EDIT**: should I implement an SSL in my VPS?

Comment: It looks like the URL you are using is not valid/correct. The error says the client could not connect. Once you have the correct URL to use you connect then send a request to the client object you created (`$client` in your example). You mentioned `obtenerReporteFinal` so it would be `$client->obtenerReporteFinal()` with whatever parameters that function requires as an array inside the `()`.

Comment: @Dave thank you for the clarification about the method. The URL works in SoapUI tool so I think it's correct.

Comment: Define "works". I should be able to "hit" it with a browser but that fails which is why I made the comment about it not being valid.

Comment: @Dave It returns the response If you try from SoapUI with the same URL and the data "Usuario","Clave","Rut","Dv" inside the '<com:obtenerReporteFinal>'.